# need help for bluetooth framework on mac osx

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, bluetooth

i'm an iOs developer and I actually need to make a mac application that use bluetooth framework to connect to another device (not iOS device).

I'm actually showing a modal view showing the connected bluetooth device with `IOBluetoothDeviceSelectorController` and I get the user choice with `[modal getResults]` but I don't know how to initiate the connection with the selected device and I can't find a simple way to do it on the mac dev library.

is anyone know a tutorial or sample code that could help me advance in my project?

linkos

Answer (score 0):

The Mac Developer Library has two sample Bluetooth projects; [connecting to a health thermometer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/HealthThermometer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011370) and [connecting to a heart rate monitor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/HeartRateMonitor/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011322). There is also video available of the [Advanced Core Bluetooth WWDC 2012 session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=705_).